# When does the product topology have a countable base?

Tags: general-topology

Could any one tell me how to prove this one?

> The product topology has a countable base if and only if the
>   topology of each coordinate space has a countable base and all
>   but a countable number of coordinate spaces are indiscrete

Comment: If one of the coordinate spaces is empty, it won't matter how many others are indiscrete.

Comment: Why would you expect that to be true? You can improve your question by giving a fuller context for where you encountered the question and what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The harder direction is to show that the product space has a countable base, then each of the factors also has a countable base, and all but countably many of them have the indiscrete topology.

Let $X=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$, and let $\mathscr{B}$ be a countable base for $X$. Fix $x=\langle x_i:i\in I\rangle\in X$. For $i\in I$ let $$Y_i=\Big\{\langle y_j:j\in I\rangle\in X:y_j=x_j\text{ for all }j\in I\setminus\{i\}\Big\}\;;$$ if $\pi_i:X\to X_i$ is the projection map, it’s a standard elementary result that $\pi_i\upharpoonright Y_i$ is a homeomorphism of $Y_i$ onto $X_i$. In particular, for each $B\in\mathscr{B}$ and $i\in I$, $\pi_i[B\cap Y_i]$ is open in $X_i$. For $i\in I$ let $\mathscr{B}_i=\{\pi_i[B\cap Y_i]:B\in\mathscr{B}\}$; clearly each $\mathscr{B}_i$ is countable, and I claim that $\mathscr{B}_i$ is a base for $X_i$.

Suppose that $p\in U\subseteq X_i$, where $U$ is open. Let $y$ be the unique point of $Y_i$ such that $\pi_i(y)=p$. Then $\pi_i^{-1}[U]$ is an open nbhd of $y$ in $X$, so there is some $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $y\in B\subseteq \pi_i^{-1}[U]$. It follows that $p\in\pi_i[B\cap Y_i]\subseteq U$, where $\pi_i[B\cap Y_i]\in\mathscr{B}_i$; this establishes the claim.

Now let $I_0$ be the set of $i\in I$ such that the topology on $X_i$ is not indiscrete, and suppose that $I_0$ is uncountable. For each $i\in I_0$ let $U_i$ be a non-empty proper open subset of $X_i$. Without loss of generality assume that the point $x$ fixed at the beginning of the proof is such that $x_i\in U_i$ for all $i\in I_0$. Then $x\in\pi_i^{-1}[U_i]$ for each $i\in I_0$, so for each $i\in I_0$ there is a $B(i)\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B(i)\subseteq\pi_i^{-1}[U_i]$. $\mathscr{B}$ is countable, and $I_0$ is uncountable, so there are a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ and an uncountable $I_1\subseteq I_0$ such that $B(i)=B$ for every $i\in I_1$. Clearly $x\in B\subseteq\prod_{i\in I_1}U_i\times\prod_{i\in I\setminus I_1}X_i$.

On the other hand, $B$ is open in the product topology on $X$, so so there are a finite $F\subseteq I$ and open sets $V_i$ in $X_i$ for $i\in F$ such that

$$x\in\prod_{i\in F}V_i\times\prod_{i\in I\setminus F}X_i\subseteq B\subseteq\prod_{i\in I_1}U_i\times\prod_{i\in I\setminus I_1}X_i\;.$$

Pick any $i\in I_1\setminus F$; then $X_i\subseteq\pi_i[B]\subseteq U_i\subsetneqq X_i$, which is absurd. Hence $I_0$ must be countable.

Answer (score 1):

$(\Rightarrow)$: Suppose $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a collection of spaces with all but countably many indiscrete, let $\{B_{ij}\}_{j\in \mathbb N}$ be a countable basis for each $X_i$, and let $X$ be their product. The sets of the form $\prod_{i\in I} B_{ij_i}$ with all but finitely many $B_{ij_i}$ equal to the whole set $X_i$ form a [basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Definition) for $X$. Note that when constructing $\prod_{i\in I} B_{ij_i}$ there are only countably many $i$ for which $B_{ij_i}$ could be not the whole set. Thus there are only countably many ways to choose a finite number of $i$ to make $B_{ij_i}$ not the whole set (since $B_{ij_i}=X_i$ for $X_i$ indiscrete). Furthermore, for any fixed choice of finitely many values of $i$ to make $B_{ij_i}$ not the whole set, there are only countably many ways to choose the $B_{ij_i}$. Thus we have a countable basis.

$(\Leftarrow)$: Suppose some $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a collection of spaces with product $X$ which has a countable basis $\{B_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$. Let $\pi_i:X\to X_i$ denote projection onto the $i^{th}$ component. Then each $X_i$ has a countable basis
$\{X_i\cap \pi_i[B_j]\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$. Furthermore, if uncountably many of the $X_i$ are indiscrete then uncountably many of the sets $\{X_i\cap \pi_i[B_j]\}_{j\in \mathbb N}$ contain sets other than $X_i$, yet for fixed $j$ this can only be true for finitely many sets (for any open set $U$ in $X$, $\pi_i(U)=X_i$ for all but finitely many $i$) and there are only countably many choices for $j$, thus we have a contradiction.

Comment: In the first sentence you want *with all but countably many indiscrete*. In the second paragraph $X_i$ isn’t a subset of $X$, so $X_i\cap B_j$ doesn’t make sense; you have to work a little harder than that.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for the correction. For $X_i\cap B_j$, the correct notation is rather torturous and the inclusion $X_i\to X$ is obvious, so I was under the impression that this was a standard abuse of notation.

Comment: I would never use it, and I’d take off for it at least in an undergraduate or first-year graduate course. (I’d comment negatively on it at any level.) At the very least it’s likely to be confusing for someone who is just learning to work with products.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I've revised the answer.

Comment: $\pi_i[B_j]\subseteq X_i$, so you don’t need to intersect it with $X_i$. However, there’s still a bit of work to do to show that $\{\pi_i[B_j]:j\in\Bbb N\}$ is a base for $X_i$: you can’t assume that the $B_j$ belong to the standard base for the product. I’ve gone ahead and written up my version of that direction.